# Office 365/SharePoint Online Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

In office 365 SharePoint Online I have document library. In document library I have 3 folders and some files are inside that folder. I have one column DateTime column. Whenever any document uploaded insider folder I want to update DateTime column value at folder level. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle this via a workflow and some additional columns.  I've added something similar to the TechNet wiki last year that might be of help

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23012.sharepoint-2010-how-to-update-parent-folders-timestamps-when-child-contents-have-been-modified.aspx

Comment: In workflow not able to get parent folder. Link you have given is only working for document set but not for folder.

Comment: Would you consider using a Document Set instead?  They offer more advantages than a folder.

Comment: No actually requirement is for folder

Comment: additionally if we take document set folder then it is updating item but as we have set workflow on item update it will fire 2 times 1 for current item and other for parent document set item so it is giving error that item is already modified by user and time.

Comment: I'll have a play about with some folders in a test site to see if I can come up with anything.